# Parameter type cannot be determined for at least one variant parameter

Tags: sql-server, azure-sql-database

I'm tring to execute stored procedure placed in SQL Database (Azure) via linked server. Local SQL Server version - 2012 (11.0.3128.0). When sp doesn't have parameters everthing is fine. With parameter I receive error:

```
DECLARE @p1 int
execute sever_name.db_name.[dbo].[sp1] @p1=1

OLE DB provider "MSDASQL" for linked server "sever_name" returned message "Parameter type cannot be determined for at least one variant parameter.".   
Msg 7212, Level 17, State 1, Line 29
Could not execute procedure 'sp1' on remote server 'sever_name'.
```

rpc=true

Comment: What DataSource have you chosen when you were defining  your linked servee? ODBC?

Comment: with Driver="SQL Server"

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem with a linked server call from 2014 over to a 2000 server today.  The fix?  Don't name the parameter:

```
execute sever_name.db_name.[dbo].[sp1] 1
```

Comment: Strangely enough this has worked for me :-). Named parameters seems not to be working between SQL 2014 and SQL 2000 (Linked server from SQL 2014 to SQL 2000). Microsoft suggest to use SQLNCLI instead of MSDASQL
https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/azure/en-US/9283d69c-8f77-49a4-bad2-3ecd468f3353/

It looks like this one could work, but I have not tested it (SQL Server Native Client 10.0 (sqlncli10.dll))
https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/a6535e6e-19ef-47b5-bee1-849446fa8cf4/